# adding uiview as a subview to the main view

Tags: iphone

i want to add an `UIView` for small size as a subview to existing view.

i have a `UIViewController` pushed with a nib name which is the main view, i am trying to create an object of `UIView` and alloc it with dimension with the following code in the viewcontroller's `viewDidLoad` methoad

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

but the idea is not suggesting the alloc on `UIView` and throwing an error if i forcefully type and run

please help me out with this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To add something (rather important) to the answers above;

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height); // Replacing with your dimensions
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

Then, you want to actually add it to the superview (assuming the view is self.view)

```
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

Comment: i am trying the same in viewdidload method of the of my viewcontroller class but the xcode is not suggesting alloc on uiview and if i forcefully copy paste this code the view if not being added as a subview to self.view

Answer (score 3):

UIView needs to be alloc'ed and init'ed with a frame:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height); // Replacing with your dimensions
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

Comment: i am trying the same in viewdidload method of the of my viewcontroller class but the xcode is not suggesting alloc on uiview and if i forcefully copy paste this code the view if not being added as a subview to self.view

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

Comment: `UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];`

You missed a bracket.